# How to load JSON data from an AJAX call in Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Good day Pals, I have had experience of the old pure JavaScript and little use of JQuery. Now, on my new JAVA Web Based project we need to use the most recent technology for raplidy build web pages that are dynamically bound.  I have not time to do Proof of concept for all the widget/JS frameworks out there, but based on my research. I have found: Old JQuery, Bootstrap, Angular Strap and Angular UI-Bootstrap. I gathered that Angular UI-Bootstrap is the most efficient of the lot, so I am settling for that.

Please, could anyone help with the following:

- Sample source or code or reference or article for using "Angular UI-Bootstrap" framework to invoke a restful web service, which returns the payload as a JSON object. Then, translates the JSON data into a format that suits a specific html control e.g. dropdown etc  I am doing a proof of concept at the moment, so any variation of the Ajax call to populate say DIV, dropdown, input text etc will be appreciated.
- Also, any good documentation or reference on best practices and application of this "Angular UI-Bootstrap"  i.e. when to use it and when to use other frameworks.

Your help and time will be so much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the help section: http://stackoverflow.com/tour StackOverflow seems to work best for answers to specific programming questions; and I think this question is too broad.  Based on the information you've given I think I could write for hours with addressing your needs / concern.  Generically, to load JSON data in an AngularJS app, I use $http ( http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great introductory video that is linked from the Angular documentation demonstrating $resource to fetch JSON data from a REST service.  It is slightly dated (the twitter feed he uses no longer works, I believe), but I think it will get you going in the right direction.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRelx4-ISbs

Remember that the UI-Bootstrap components are just that: UI components.  Just by adding the appropriate includes for the bootstrap ui css and js, you can then use them in your app.

I'm sure you've seen it, but the Angular Bootstrap UI documentation includes live code examples and is very helpful: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

If you have more specific questions, post away, but I hope that gets you going.  I'm using this same stack for my application and it looks and works very nicely.

ken.

Comment: Thanks Ken and Reboog711. I've had a quick scan at the references.  Q: Ken, did you mean "Angular UI-Bootstrap" framework only contains html n css i.e. ui component, while AngularJS is the JavaScript library it uses? Are both libraries maintained in one github repo. Reason, I am asking is. I am tasked to do more JS frontend work and will not be interested in more html css tricks. I will leave that to my wed designer. Just wanted to know if i should be mentioning more of AngularJS when researching into things, than saying "Angular UI-Bootstrap" ... Is there a separate repo for AngularJS?

Comment: Hello fellas, I now have a real issue when trying the resource you send me ... please revise the thread: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766339/consuming-a-restful-web-service-with-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment32931903_21766339[/link]

Comment: Hi!  Yes, AngularJS is its own thing (http://angularjs.org/ == a google javascript framework/platform).

Comment: Ooops -- hit enter too fast: Angular UI is actually also its own project (http://angular-ui.github.io/) with a number of great UI elements, including Bootstrap.  It sounds like mostly what you're looking for is AngularJS, but you'll probably need to understand what the UI components are consuming so you can serve and receive them on the backend.  Enjoy!